# gdisk doesn't recognize RAID0 disk as size of whole array?

Tags: partitioning, raid, raid-0, intel-rst, gdisk

I put in two Samsung 840s at 256GB and RAID-ed them together and installed Windows 8.

I'm having trouble using gdisk to get ready to install Linux.

gdisk sees the array, /dev/sda0, as a whole drive, but the size value comes from the individual disk as opposed to the individual disks combined. The graphic user interface, gparted, throws out a bunch of errors.

I'm using Intel RST to do a RAID0.

How do I fix my disk to make gdisk work?

> root@ubuntu:~# gdisk /dev/sda GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 0.8.8
>
> Warning! Disk size is smaller than the main header indicates! Loading
>   secondary header from the last sector of the disk! You should use 'v'
>   to verify disk integrity, and perhaps options on the experts' menu to
>   repair the disk. Caution: invalid backup GPT header, but valid main
>   header; regenerating backup header from main header.
>
> Warning! One or more CRCs don't match. You should repair the disk!
>
> Partition table scan:   MBR: protective   BSD: not present   APM: not
>   present   GPT: damaged
>
> **************************************************************************** Caution: Found protective or hybrid MBR and corrupt GPT. Using GPT,
>   but disk verification and recovery are STRONGLY recommended.
>
> ---
>
> Command (? for help): v
>
> Caution: The CRC for the backup partition table is invalid. This table
>   may be corrupt. This program will automatically create a new backup
>   partition table when you save your partitions.
>
> Problem: The secondary header's self-pointer indicates that it doesn't
>   reside at the end of the disk. If you've added a disk to a RAID array,
>   use the 'e' option on the experts' menu to adjust the secondary
>   header's and partition table's locations.
>
> Problem: Disk is too small to hold all the data! (Disk size is
>   488397168 sectors, needs to be 976783360 sectors.) The 'e' option on
>   the experts' menu may fix this problem.
>
> Problem: GPT claims the disk is larger than it is! (Claimed last
>   usable sector is 976783326, but backup header is at 976783359 and disk
>   size is 488397168 sectors. The 'e' option on the experts' menu will
>   probably fix this problem
>
> Problem: partition 2 is too big for the disk.
>
> Identified 5 problems!
>
> Command (? for help):

Using 'e' in the expert menu doesn't fix the problem.
Also the problem persists in gdisk 0.8.10

Comment: if you use gpart on a raw DISK (e.g. on /dev/sda) then you will see the disk. You probably want to run in on the ARRAY (e.g. /dev/md0 for Linux based RAID and /dev/dm0 for irsst based RAID).